# material ui : Change Defualt font Family Listitem Text Material Ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
<ListItem disablePadding key={index}>
            <Link to={data.loc}>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <data.icon color={setColor(page, data.index,'secondary','primary')} />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText
                  primary={data.name}
                  style={{color:setColor(page,data.index,'#FBC02D','white'),fontFamily:'Vazir'}}
                />
              </ListItemButton>
            </Link>
 </ListItem>
```

im wana fix this code change fontfamily but
i see in elemnt in dev tools not changed

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRBge.png)

[my font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhmHh.png)

//output:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFXZ3.png)

Comment: you should add more information about your code like are you using this font in another place of your code or not , you should add a font your project then you can use it naming is important too , have a look at this, it might help you https://fontserver.ir/font/Vazir

Comment: thanks but im used font in Other code but here im have problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im fixe the problem

just add  disableTypography={true}

into ListItemText

[image code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQpHs.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
ListItem:{
      '& span, & svg': {
      fontFamily: "fontName" ,
      fontSize: '1rem'  },
      color:' darkGreen' ,
      paddingLeft: 20,
      
    },
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.